# outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:tableColumn is called more than necessary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This method is invoked every time I click on a row of my NSOutlineView. I thought it was supposed to be invoked only once for each column-row in order to create the cell:

```
 - (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
 {

      if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
          CBImageTextCell *cell = [[CBImageTextCell alloc] init];
          ...
          return [cell autorelease];
      }
 }
```

Consequently am I initializing more cells than necessary ?

The reason why I'm digging into this code is that when I click on one cell, **hitTestForEvent** is invoked twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is expected that it will be called whenever the outline view needs the cell.  The outline view does not necessarily store the cell. Certainly, it does not store a cell for every column-row. Table and outline views store very little. They get the content from the data source every time it's needed and they ask the delegate or the columns for cells every time, etc.

If the cell is always of the same class, you should probably just set an instance of that class as the cell of the column and not implement this delegate method. You can set it in IB or in code.  If you simply need to tweak the cell for each row, implement `-outlineView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:item:` instead.